# Why is fprintf not printing anything in the file?

Tags: c, printf

Why is it not printing anything in the file. I tested with fputs and it's also not working.
It is bugging me, because I'm just using scanf to get a string and passing it to the function fprintf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZEBUFFER 401

int main(){
  FILE *arq;
  char file_name[44], text_buffer[SIZEBUFFER];
  char action, action2;
  int again = 1;
  while(1){
    printf("What do you want? ");
    scanf(" %c", &action);
    switch(action){
      case 'N': case 'n':
        printf("Type the file name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", file_name);
        strcat(file_name, ".txt");
        arq = fopen(file_name, "a+");
        rewind(arq);
        do{
          printf("What do you want now? ");
          scanf(" %c", &action2);
          switch(action2){
            case 'W': case 'w':
              printf("Type the paragraph: \n\n");
              scanf( " %[^\n]s", text_buffer);
              fprintf(arq, "%s\n", text_buffer);
              break;
            case '0':
              again = 0;
              break;
          }
          putchar('\n');
        }while(again);
        again = 1;
        break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about replacing `fprintf` with `printf` and seeing if it is printing on the screen? If it doesn't, you might want to use a debugger.

Comment: I miss the file close or flush ...

Comment: With printf, it's working.

Comment: Why the unnneded `s` in `" %[^\n]s"`? Without a width limit, `scanf(" %[^\n]s", file_name);` is worse than `gets()`.

Comment: Post input used.

Comment: Look up the buffering policy of different streams. ;-)